# Focus-within css style doesn't add border

Tags: html, css, accessibility

I cannot understand how `focus-within` works. I want to add a border when buttons are focused. This is minimal working example. Why doesn't it add the border around the div on the button focus?

```css
.accordion:focus-within {
  border-color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion">
 <h3>
  <button>First button</button>
 </h3>
 <h3>
  <button>Second button</button>
 </h3>
 <h3>
  <button>Third button</button>
 </h3>
</div>
<div class="accordion">
 <h3>
  <button>4th button</button>
 </h3>
 <h3>
  <button>5th button</button>
 </h3>
 <h3>
  <button>6th button</button>
 </h3>
</div> 

<div class="accordion">
<h3>
  <button>7th button</button>
 </h3>
 <h3>
  <button>8th button</button>
 </h3>
 <h3>
  <button>9th button</button>
 </h3> 
</div>
```

Comment: You've not defined a border size, only a color, so that wouldn't be visible; also buttons don't take `focus` (you'd need to at least add a `tabindex` to them.)

Answer (score 0):

You currently forgot to add some borders, so that making it blue doesnt change anything. Here is code that should help you to move forward:

```
.accordion:focus-within {
  border-color: blue;
  border-style: solid;
  border-width: 5px;
}
```

You see, that when button is focused, solid 5px thick border of blue color is made.